# Xcode 4.2/IOS 5 Segmentation fault on exit of newly created project for Device

Tags: xcode, segmentation-fault, ios5

Since upgrading to XCode 4.2, I noticed a problem and I am at a lost on what to do.  Here are the steps to reproduce:

1) Create a new xcode project, an iphone empty project with no options enabled.
2) Go to main.m and just make main into "return 0;"
3) Set minimum OS to 3.3 (I haven't updated my ipod touch 2nd gen yet)
4) Build and Run

It seems to build and run okay, but if you look in the device console in the xcode organizer you see the following errors:

```
<Warning>: 1 [0698/1403]: error: ::read ( 4, 0x3807f0, 1024 ) => -1 err = Bad file descriptor (0x00000009)

<Warning>: Application 'Test' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

I am thinking that perhaps I am missing a file?  But I'm not sure what file I am missing.  Everything else in the new project is set to the default.  If I make it print out something then exit with 0, I can see the output, but then I do not see the exit code because it has crashed as above.

If I Build and Run for simulator I see no errors in the console output of the simulator.